# Angular preloading google map

Tags: angular

I am trying to create webpage with angular containing a google map. The map is taking a while to load. Is there is way to preload the map together with the app so the user see only the already loaded map?

Comment: Could you pls provide some code or update your question to be more detail?

Comment: no code online, what details need?

Comment: Like, is this AngularJS or Angular2+ project?

Comment: yes it Angular 2

Comment: Do you use Angular CLI?

Comment: yes i do angularcli

Comment: How did you implement Google Maps?

Comment: what implement, normal

Comment: Like external script in webpack, inline script in index file, some npm module?

Comment: Script. What npm?

Comment: NPM as in npmjs.org, there is AGM module that can help you.

Comment: what AGM, script?

Comment: Yes, its a module, something like a library, also available here https://angular-maps.com/ ... Do you have any control over your server?

Comment: not sure, just used firebase for first

Comment: OK, I think you you should do some reading, I will try to compose some answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since the original question is too broad and the comments under it incline to form an extensive debate, this is a mere summary of suggestions to follow in dealing with Google Maps in Angular2+ webpages hosted on Firebase:*

**1) Use AGM**

Although there are many ways to implement Google Maps in Angular2+ webpage, since you use Angular CLI,  I would suggest you to use some well-established  and well-documented NPM modules. My weapon of choice is [Angular Google Maps (AGM)](https://angular-maps.com/) . Such ready-made modules truly ease the pain, especially while dealing with issues such as optimising loading of the app.

**2) Listen to map being ready**

Generally speaking you have two options when it comes to 'preloading' the page. First, create an global initial loading screen that will be displayed until all page resources are available. Second, place some kind of graphics indicating loading in progress instead of each element which is being fetched and remove this partial element once the data is rendered. Indeed, you can combine both to conform large-scale apps. Nonetheless, you have to listen to the map being ready. AGM provides you with a mapReady event emitter -> the event is emitted as components output, hence you can trigger an function when the even occurs. Following code illustrates basic implementation of Angular2+ *ngIf in combination with AGM mapReady directly in the template (you might want to move the logic out of the template in larger app or using ng-container or ngClass to manage the spinner).

Assuming you created spinner as separate component, you can conditionally replace AGM map with it like this:

in your some.component.html file:

```
        <app-spinner *ngIf="!map_loaded"></app-spinner>

        <agm-map [latitude]=your_marker_latitude
            [longitude]=your_marker_longitude
            [zoom]=your_map_zoom
            [fullscreenControl]=your_map_fullscreen_control
            [mapTypeControl]=your_map_type_control
            [streetViewControl]=your_map_streetview_control
            [zoomControl]=your_map_zoom_control
            (mapReady)="map_loaded = true">
            <agm-marker [latitude]=your_marker_latitude [longitude]=your_marker_longitude></agm-marker>
        </agm-map>
```

in your some.component.scss file:

```
    .MapContainer {
    ...some overal styling for the parent container

      app-spinner,
      agm-map {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;   
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    }
```

**3) Cache as much as you can**

In order to make the app as swift as possible, consider caching all you can. The final solution would depend on your specific needs, but make sure that above modules such as [angular2-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cache)
  and articles such as [Angular — Simple In Memory Cache](https://hackernoon.com/angular-simple-in-memory-cache-service-on-the-ui-with-rxjs-77f167387e39)
 you also read on how to [Enable Offline Data for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

Comment: this seems not good, have some video?

Comment: No, I have none. You have asked very broadly and provided very little information. Unless, you update your question, I cannot really help you more, than to point you to some specific resources.

Comment: ok i understand